# Method compile() not found

Tags: android, dependencies

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\cobzer\Desktop\KayLek-TeamBarkelou\app\build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:design:25.0.1] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support', name='appcompat-v7', version='25.0.1', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` code here. Also edit your title to something like `Could not find method compile() for arguments`

Comment: @Shelby115 I approved your edit. May I give a small tip for editing? Look at the tags. The "conflict" tag that the OP used clearly said "DO NOT USE", so I removed that too. Keep up the good work!